# Sharing files between docker containers when one is the host of the other one

Tags: docker, containers

I am trying to call a docker container inside of another container (host container).
I made the bellow docker file for the host container:

```
#container1
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -qy full-upgrade && \
    apt-get install -qy curl && \
    apt-get install -qy curl && \
    curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
RUN mkdir -p /user-data-container1/
WORKDIR /user-data-container1/
COPY bash-script.sh /user-data-container1/bash-script.sh
```

In which in `bash-script.sh` I call the other docker container by calling:

```
docker run --rm -t --name stream \
-v /user-data-container1/:/user-data-container2/:rw\
     container2 bash /user-data/bash-script.sh
```

The `container2` is a pre-built container and I can not change any file inside that. In `/user-data-container1` there are some files that should be shared with the `container2` however it seems that the shared volume is empty since `/user-data-container2/` is empty when I run `ls /user-data-container2/` in the above command.

now I am trying to call the bash script in the 2nd container on the 1st container by calling the below command:

```
docker run -p 8085:3000 -v  $(pwd):/user-data-container2/:rw \
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  \
-it test-image bash /user-data-container1/bash-script.sh
```

I am wondering what is the issue that the files on `container1` in `/user-data-container1/` are not shared with the `container2` in `/user-data-container2/`

Comment: You can't mount files from one container to another, and Docker doesn't know that the `docker run` request is being launched from a container.  The linked question has an extensive answer detailing the options.  I'd also consider creating a new image `FROM image2` that `COPY`s the files into it, rather than trying to share them live.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I can not build image2 since it is a paid container and I didnt make it and am not able to build or change it. Is there any other option?

Comment: You can create a derived image `FROM` any other image; there's no technical barrier to creating your own image based on a closed-source third-party image (there may be legal barriers).